# Adding a png image and table html while sending email in Jenkins

Tags: python, html, jenkins, png, email-ext

I am using Jenkins email extension plugin and would like to do two things:

1. Attach a png image to the email
2. And also render html into the email message.

The email should contain both png image and rendered html.

If I attach png image and render html into message body using a pre-send script written in Groovy I do not get the attachment.

If I attach both html file and png image I get rendered image but the html file appears as a file attachment.

What should I do to get both html and img rendered in the email message body.

I have Jenkins ver. 1.614

Comment: What configuration have you tried so far?

Comment: In the editable email extension: I specified image.png into attachments. And used a pre-send script to copy and render html into the msg body. However with this set up I only get the html emailed but image.png is not attached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add your attachment and set default content with a path to html file. Pre-send script not needed for this:

[image]

**Note**: do not forget to set appropriate content type.

Comment: I had setup the things you had mentioned but in outlook and gmail email image is not displayed as inline content. However image is displayed in thunderbird. I don't know why??? any idea?

Comment: @DineshDhiman Sorry, I have no idea. It is properly displayed for me in outlook and gmail.

Comment: Could you please share the html code of report.html and email server configuration.

Comment: @DineshDhiman `report.html` is a pretty standard html file with `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags and some content inside. Unfortunately, i can't share email server configuration because i have no access to it.

Comment: How to add Style css in template