# Capture screenshots on failure with Selenium + Python + Jenkins

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins, screenshot, jenkins-plugins

I have written my scripts in Selenium Python. In the Jenkins, I have added Publish JUnit test results report(http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/xunit.html). However, I want to add the screenshot in that report as well. I feel like my tests are not useful without screenshots. How can I achieve this? I also would like receive error screenshots as attachments in my email.

Can I achieve this just by using a Jenkins plugin? or I need to add something in my selenium script? I am not able to find anything useful in selenium python.

I went over the following question, but it does explain the full process
[Adding a png image and table html while sending email in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732095/adding-a-png-image-and-table-html-while-sending-email-in-jenkins)

Please help.....

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, How you are linking the failed test case to the screenshot.